# Ballerina Enable or disable JMS connection

Tags: ballerina

In ballerina JMS is a service and so if we want to initiate JMS connection only in a specific condition we cannot achive that. So is it possible to achive it? If not is there any way to start the JMS service based on the condition?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot start a service based on a condition in Ballerina.

Comment: If so what is the recommended way to enable and disable that feature. Say we have JMS based throttling. Which can be enable or disabled based on the config.

Comment: Since you cannot start a service based on a condition from ballerina language itself, you will have to start it using a separate script like bash.